# Memory efficient way to make changes to CSV files and merge result into one large CSV using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a lot of log files, structured as seen below:

`logs
   |
    -- machine1
   |       |
   |        -- day1
   |       |    |
   |       |     -- machine1_timestamp11.log
   |       |     -- machine1_timestamp12.log
   |       |
   |        -- day2
   |       |    |
   |       |     -- machine1_timestamp21.log
   |
    -- machine2
   |       |
   |        -- day1
   |       |     |
   .       .     .`

The log files keep track of the state of a machine and it is possible that there is information of interest in two consecutive log files.

My end goal is to merge all log files for a given day, and then split them again s.t. I only have log files of time consecutive data, where the state of the machine is of interest. Each logfile is named according to when the logging started, and there is a `timeOffset` column in the CSV. Hence I aspire to add `timeOffset + timestamp` to a new column and use this column to keep track of which entry goes where in the merged file.

Given a CSV, I have already figured out how to split it into "interesting parts", but due to the large amount of data (typically ~5GiB/day) I am unable to get the merging to work.

There are four alternatives as far as I see:

1. Get more RAM.
2. Make use of some clever streaming of the data to avoid reading all logfiles into memory.
3. Preprocess the logfiles such that the filtering process has already taken place. Albeit, I still think these resulting log files would be too large.
4. Read a log file, add the necessary data, write it as a new CSV to disk. Then -- for all remaining log files -- read another logfile, add necessary data, append it to the CSV.

The code below does the trick (I think), but I run out of RAM when running it for most days.

```
def main():

    # Acquire list of all log files
    files = glob.glob(root + 'logs/day1/*.log', recursive = True)

    # Create a dataframe for each file
    dfs = list()
    for path in files:

        # Extract machine ID and time stamp from filename
        file_name = path.split("/")[-1]
        machine = file_name.split("_")[0]
        unix_ms_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(file_name.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0])/1000.0)
        date = unix_ms_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        # Read data from file
        df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = ';')

        # Add a time column to allow for continuity between files
        df["time"] = unix_ms_time + pd.to_timedelta(df["timeOffset"], unit = "ms")

        # Add each dataframe to list
        dfs.append(df)

    # Concatenate all frames, the resulting frames contains all log data for
    # one particular day and machine
    result = pd.concat(dfs)

    # Write result to disk
    root_save = "merged/"
    save_path = "{}{}_{}.csv".format(root_save, machine, date)
    print("Saving to: {}".format(save_path))
    result.to_csv(save_path)
```

Alternative "Buy more RAM" is out of the question, but I would like some input on how to proceed with the alternatives.

Comment: Why not create each output file that will be the result of the split then go through each individual log appending each "interesting" part to the appropriate output file? Why exactly do you need to merge them?

Comment: read_csv has a chunksize argument that can be used to read a file in chunks. by designing code that reads a file in chunks then processes and finally stores those chunks you never read in the entire file at once which should prevent a memory error.

Comment: Don't use pandas for that IMHO. Just create a file, process your logfiles one by one and then append lines to the already created file. This is much more efficient and as far as I see the only reason you use pandas is for reading in the csv, which is a lot of overhead while direct reading and appending like: `with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("appended text")` can do the trick